# IServiceCollection post configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following line of code using an `IServiceCollection` it resides in an extension method called during startup.

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>, PolicyRegistry>();
```

I need to call some methods on the `PolicyRegistry` before its used. What is the most elegant way to achieve this using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?

Multiple different projects might call `TryAddSingleton` using the `PolicyRegistry` and needing to set its policies in it before being used in any constructor.

What I'm looking for is something like `PostConfiguration` for `IOptions`.

```
services.PostConfigure<PolicyRegistry>(x => PostConfig(x));
```

Comment: Does `PolicyRegistry` have any dependencies that also need to be injected?

Comment: why not call the method inside your constructor, when an instance is created constructor will be called always. You can wire up your method from there

Comment: `PolicyRegistry ` has an empty constructor. `PolicyRegistry` is not within my control.